# iOS 'reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler' deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c

A part of code (I didn't write) is shown as deprecated in my Xcode project, here's the code block:

```
#pragma mark - Report Achievement Progress
static int reportAchievement(struct lua_State *state) {
    [gameCenterAddOnInstance reportAchievementAction:[NSString stringWithCString:lua_tostring(state, 1) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] percentComplete:(int)lua_tointeger(state, 2)];
    
    return 1;
}

- (void) reportAchievementAction: (NSString*) identifier percentComplete: (float) percent
{
    GKAchievement *achievement = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: identifier];
    if (achievement)
    {
        achievement.percentComplete = percent;
        [achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
         {
             if (error != nil)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

According to Xcode, the depreciated part is:

```
reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler
```

Xcode suggests to use:

```
reportAchievements:WithCompletionHandler:
```

Instead. But, not being familiar with objective C, I wouldn't know where to start.

How to implement to new function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[GKAchievement reportAchievements:@[achievement] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
     {
         if (error != nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);
         }
     }];
```

Apple replaced the instance method `- reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:` with the class method `+ reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler:`. This allows you to report multiple achievements at once without having to call the instance method on every achievement object.

`@[achievement]` is shorthand for `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:achievement, nil]`.